# mariadb galera load data infile no auto increment primairy key

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, mariadb, load-data-infile, galera

I have a mariaddb galera cluster (multi master of 3) and need to do large bulk inserts. The fastest way I've seen and used is via load data local infile. The table is of the type INNODB

This works when the table I'm inserting into has a primairy key that has an auto-icrement value.

However, since I changed the primairy key to be a unique key based on 3 columns (date, vouchernumber and type) where the voucher number and date can be the same but not the type. This no longer works.

In php the error return is about Packets out of order, not very helpful. Running it directly via mysql the returend error is:

ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Searching for this does not provide a clear answer, but I suspect that it is caused because of the multi-master cluster that normally makes inserts unique due to the insert auto_increment and auto_increment_offset and clusternode number managed by the overlaying cluster manager.  http://codership.blogspot.nl/2009/02/managing-auto-increments-with-multi.html

I think that the LOAD DATA INFILE only works using a primairy key with auto-increment.

But I'm not sure, therefore this question to confirm this or help me solving the issue via other parameters.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is possible, it works in another part of my code. That table has no auto-increment key. Why I don't know yet.

Comment: The cause appears to be the table partitioning that I have on it. Removing it makes the import possible. Still looking into this as I would like to use the table partitioning.